# Second request to API results in empty string

Tags: php

First request to API:

```
    $siteUrl = $this->getConfig()->get('siteUrl');
    $headers = array(
        "Espo-Authorization: " . $this->getEncodedLoginData()
    );

    $curl = curl_init($siteUrl . '/api/v1/Account');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$response) {
        $GLOBALS['log']->addWarning('curlerr: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($response, true);
```

I get accounts info as expected. But when i try to do next request after some manipulations with accounts, in response i get empty string.
There is an example of next request:

```
    $siteUrl = $this->getConfig()->get('siteUrl');
    $headers = array(
        "Espo-Authorization: " . $this->getEncodedLoginData()
    );

    $curl = curl_init($siteUrl . '/api/v1/Contacts');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$response) {
        $GLOBALS['log']->addWarning('curlerr: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
```

Doing requests to API from browser works properly.

Comment: Do you get any useful info from the error message?

Comment: There are no errors.. :(

Comment: Maybe you might send some parameters via POST in order to complete the API call.

Comment: Here docs about api, i don't think i need POST request before second GET https://www.espocrm.com/documentation/development/api/

Comment: In the docs when the call to /api/v1/Contacts is made they send an ID after Contacts. You might be missing this and that's why no data is returned. Try to concat the ID in your second curl URL

Comment: Without ID tag request must return all data in Contacts Entity

Answer (score 0):

Problem were in login/pass data. I don't know exactly how, but login/pass vars were changed before executing second request. Thanks for assistance!